# Cypress: cy.type() requires a valid time with the format with the format HH:mm, HH:mm:ss or HH:mm:ss.SSS

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, cypress

I am automating using cypress, there is a time input in the application. The html of it as follows:

```
<label>Time</label>
<input data-testid="time" type="time" name="time" class="u-full-width" value="" wtx-context="95580C00-C3AB-4D06-ADCC-29340AA4B7E2">
```

The code that I used to identify the element is:

```
 timeInput(){
        return cy.get('[data-testid=time]');
    }
```

Code to enter data in it is:

```
 formCreateAppointmentPageElements.timeInput().click().type("01:52:08 AM");
```

When I run the test, cypress gives this error:

```
CypressError
Typing into a time input with cy.type() requires a valid time with the format HH:mm, HH:mm:ss or HH:mm:ss.SSS, where HH is 00-23, mm is 00-59, ss is 00-59, and SSS is 000-999. You passed: 01:52:08 AM Learn more
cypress/pages/FormCreateAppointmentPage.js:9:63
   7 |         formCreateAppointmentPageElements.ownerNameInput().type("Reena");
   8 |         formCreateAppointmentPageElements.dateInput().click().type("2022-01-23");
>  9 |         formCreateAppointmentPageElements.timeInput().click().type("01:52:08 AM");
     |                                                               ^
```

Also, cypress does type 01:52:08 AM in the time input, highlights the 01 and throws the error.
But the error says, you passed, what does that mean? Am I not providing the time in the right format?
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there are only [three allowed formats for input type time](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type#Time-Inputs):

> - HH:mm (e.g. 01:30 or 23:15)
> - HH:mm:ss (e.g. 10:00:30)
> - HH:mm:ss.SSS (e.g. 12:00:00.384)

You can also use [`.invoke()` command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke):

```javascript
cy
  .get('[data-testid=time]')
  .invoke('val', '01:52:08 AM');
```

Basically whatever is possible in JavaScript is possible in Cypress. So here you can invoke [jQuery `val()` method](https://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Thankyou! If I eliminate the Am/PM it works fine!